# read SVHN dataset in tensorflow

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow

I try to train the street view house numbers (SVHN) data in this tutorial ([Convolutional Neural Networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn)) 
I used

> scipy.io.loadmat

but it does not work, and gives me this error::

> TypeError: Expected string, got {'**header**': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Mon Dec  5 21:09:26 2011', '**version**': '1.0', '**globals**': [], 'X': array([[[[ 33,  84,  19, ...,  92, 190, 216],
>            [ 30,  76,  54, ...,  78, 188, 217],
>            [ 38,  59, 110, ..., 101, 191, 212]],

```
    [[ 15,  86,  20, ...,  94, 205, 221],
     [ 23,  73,  52, ...,  82, 203, 222],
     [ 19,  66, 111, ..., 105, 206, 217]],

    [[ 15,  77,  25, ..., 114, 220, 226],
     [ 17,  78,  57, ..., 101, 218, 227],
     [ 19,  56, 116, ..., 125, 220, 221]],

    ..., 
    [[ 72,  90,  65, ..., 200, 229, 200],
     [ 65,  78, 144, ..., 201, 231, 199],
     [ 56,  69, 223, ..., 203, 224, 191]],

    [[ 82,  88,  78, ..., 192, 229, 193],
     [ 77,  77, 148, ..., 193, 229, 188],
     [ 57,  67, 218, ..., 195, 224, 182]],

    [[ 89,  88,  98, ..., 190, 229, 197],
     [ 79,  78, 158, ..., 191, 228, 189],
     [ 59,  66, 220, ..., 193, 223, 186]]],


   [[[ 28,  85,  21, ...,  92, 183, 204],
     [ 39,  77,  53, ...,  78, 182, 205],
     [ 35,  61, 110, ..., 103, 186, 202]],

    [[ 14,  83,  19, ...,  93, 200, 210],
     [ 25,  73,  52, ...,  80, 199, 211],
     [ 22,  64, 106, ..., 106, 201, 208]],

    [[ 14,  74,  25, ..., 111, 218, 220],
     [ 20,  69,  56, ...,  98, 217, 221],
     [ 17,  59, 111, ..., 124, 218, 217]],

    ..., 
    [[ 40,  89,  63, ..., 181, 227, 201],
     [ 39,  82, 137, ..., 180, 228, 199],
     [ 50,  64, 208, ..., 184, 223, 193]],

    [[ 67,  88,  91, ..., 177, 227, 195],
     [ 58,  79, 153, ..., 176, 226, 191],
     [ 52,  70, 214, ..., 180, 222, 186]],

    [[ 83,  88, 130, ..., 183, 228, 196],
     [ 78,  81, 180, ..., 182, 224, 190],
     [ 60,  67, 229, ..., 187, 221, 186]]],


   [[[ 40,  83,  21, ...,  99, 171, 198],
     [ 41,  76,  53, ...,  84, 170, 198],
     [ 38,  60, 110, ..., 112, 175, 197]],

    [[ 18,  78,  20, ...,  94, 189, 202],
     [ 21,  77,  51, ...,  81, 189, 202],
     [ 26,  58, 106, ..., 110, 193, 201]],

    [[ 16,  61,  22, ..., 107, 213, 212],
     [ 17,  50,  52, ...,  94, 213, 211],
     [ 23,  54, 106, ..., 123, 215, 210]],

    ..., 
    [[ 23,  90,  79, ..., 167, 231, 203],
     [ 29,  85, 147, ..., 166, 230, 200],
     [ 45,  63, 210, ..., 171, 226, 196]],

    [[ 35,  88, 125, ..., 172, 229, 198],
     [ 42,  83, 181, ..., 171, 226, 194],
     [ 44,  66, 230, ..., 176, 223, 191]],

    [[ 72,  85, 178, ..., 185, 227, 195],
     [ 69,  82, 218, ..., 184, 223, 190],
     [ 53,  70, 254, ..., 189, 220, 187]]],


   ..., 
   [[[ 86, 100,  88, ...,  99, 187, 233],
     [ 81,  98, 162, ...,  94, 185, 226],
     [ 75,  72, 237, ..., 110, 186, 228]],

    [[ 87,  98,  89, ...,  96, 204, 230],
     [ 82,  94, 163, ...,  91, 202, 224],
     [ 71,  76, 238, ..., 109, 199, 225]],

    [[ 82,  95,  84, ..., 108, 217, 228],
     [ 79,  93, 156, ..., 103, 217, 223],
     [ 65,  73, 230, ..., 124, 210, 221]],

    ..., 
    [[104, 104,  62, ..., 210, 204, 198],
     [104, 104, 142, ..., 207, 200, 196],
     [ 87,  86, 227, ..., 204, 195, 190]],

    [[104, 102,  67, ..., 206, 196, 184],
     [105, 102, 144, ..., 202, 193, 183],
     [ 81,  87, 226, ..., 200, 189, 177]],

    [[103, 100,  74, ..., 203, 196, 189],
     [105, 101, 145, ..., 197, 193, 187],
     [ 78,  78, 225, ..., 199, 189, 182]]],


   [[[ 84, 103,  88, ...,  94, 186, 231],
     [ 86, 104, 164, ...,  91, 184, 226],
     [ 64,  79, 240, ..., 103, 185, 228]],

    [[ 86, 106,  87, ...,  94, 198, 229],
     [ 79, 104, 160, ...,  91, 197, 224],
     [ 72,  79, 237, ..., 104, 194, 225]],

    [[ 82, 103,  88, ..., 110, 211, 227],
     [ 76, 103, 159, ..., 107, 211, 223],
     [ 72,  87, 237, ..., 121, 204, 222]],

    ..., 
    [[110, 103,  60, ..., 219, 222, 195],
     [103, 104, 141, ..., 218, 216, 194],
     [ 84,  86, 230, ..., 215, 212, 186]],

    [[106, 103,  61, ..., 218, 214, 181],
     [105, 103, 141, ..., 215, 209, 181],
     [ 85,  87, 228, ..., 212, 205, 173]],

    [[106, 105,  65, ..., 212, 208, 186],
     [104,  99, 143, ..., 209, 205, 183],
     [ 86,  81, 226, ..., 209, 200, 177]]],


   [[[ 85, 103,  84, ...,  88, 190, 230],
     [ 88, 106, 160, ...,  87, 188, 226],
     [ 68,  82, 238, ...,  94, 190, 227]],

    [[ 89, 103,  81, ...,  85, 199, 230],
     [ 82, 105, 154, ...,  84, 197, 226],
     [ 72,  87, 233, ...,  93, 194, 227]],

    [[ 85, 104,  87, ..., 105, 208, 229],
     [ 79, 106, 158, ..., 103, 208, 225],
     [ 67,  91, 238, ..., 114, 201, 226]],

    ..., 
    [[111, 113,  63, ..., 217, 232, 190],
     [104, 103, 144, ..., 217, 227, 190],
     [ 87,  88, 235, ..., 214, 223, 181]],

    [[109, 104,  62, ..., 221, 226, 178],
     [105, 104, 143, ..., 220, 221, 177],
     [ 86,  88, 232, ..., 219, 216, 169]],

    [[103, 103,  63, ..., 218, 218, 181],
     [106,  98, 145, ..., 217, 213, 178],
     [ 79,  80, 231, ..., 218, 209, 171]]]], dtype=uint8), 'y': array([[1],
   [9],
   [2],
   ..., 
   [1],
   [6],
   [9]], dtype=uint8)} of type 'dict' instead.
```

I cannot understand the problem, and what is the solution.

Comment: Hello!
Wondering if you got it done? Can you share your github? I'm very curious how did you get it done as I'm trying the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial uses the approach of reading data from files which is typical for cases where the dataset is too large to remain in memory. There's a number of steps within that part of the tutorial, mostly implemented in `cifar10_input.py`, and they generally follow the steps [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#reading_from_files).

`cifar10_input.py` takes a list of strings of filenames from which to read data. Without seeing more of your code, I'm guessing that's why you got that specific error.

You would either need to ensure the SVHN `.mat` file has the correct expected binary format (which I doubt is the case) and then swap that file name in `cifar10_input.py` for the cifar10 binary files, or rewrite `cifar10_train.py` to use a placeholder and feed_dict argument in place of a reading pipeline. Remember the SVHN will need to be cut down to the same size as the cifar images are in `cifar10_input.py`. Additionally the SVHN dataset may be too large for a feed_dict approach.